# Play! issue with @Before, traits, and Squeryl throwing closed connections?

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

**Updated Question** After some further debugging I've updated this question to be more accurate on the actual problem.

I have a trait I've defined to do a basic security check but every time I want to run a DB query it throws a `Cannot operate on a closed connection!!!` error.

Code below:

```
trait SecureAPI {
  self:Controller =>

  @Before
  def checkKey(key:String)
    models.Account.getByKey(key) match {
      case account:Account  =>  {
        renderArgs += "account" -> accountId
        Continue
      }
      case _  =>  Forbidden("Key is not authorized.")
    }
}
```

The `getByKey` throws the DB error. In my controllers, I'm adding `Squeryl` as a trait, but how would I apply that in another trait so I can continue to run queries? Or am I just not approaching this properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got deeper into different readings and credit for this one goes to this post here: http://www.alvarocarrasco.com/2010/12/i-have-settled-on-new-platform-for.html

I had to use Squeryl to bind the session to the current thread. So to make the above code work, I had to add in `SessionFactory`

```
@Before
def checkKey(key:String)
  SessionFactory.newSession.bindToCurrentThread // added this here
  models.Account....
```

Everything now queries, just need to work out a few bugs. I'll update the answer if I discover any more caveats.